# aws cognito list-users function only returns 60 users

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

I need to list all users of the cognito user-pool.
Is there any way to **return all users** of the user-pool?

The list_users-function of boto3 - client like in the following code only returns 60 users instead of all of them.

```
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp',
                         region_name=aws_region,
                         aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key,
                         aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_key,
                         config=config)

print('Setup client')

response = client.list_users(
UserPoolId=userpool_id,
AttributesToGet=[
    'email','sub'
] 
)
```

The expected result is a list of json-objects that includes all users of the cognito user-group

Answer (score 10):

@A.Khan's answer is correct. Below I've coded up 1 way to do this:

```
def get_all_users():
    cognito = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
    
    users = []
    next_page = None
    kwargs = {
        'UserPoolId': "whatever_your_user_pool_id_is"
    }

    users_remain = True
    while users_remain:
        if next_page:
            kwargs['PaginationToken'] = next_page
        response = cognito.list_users(**kwargs)
        users.extend(response['Users'])
        next_page = response.get('PaginationToken', None)
        users_remain = next_page is not None

    return users
```

Comment: Update - use *NextToken* (*PaginationToken* is failing)

Answer (score 9):

You are seeing the expected result. You can request 60 or less users at a time. You will need to use pagination token to be able to go through all the users exist in the user pool. See the [API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html) specifically `Limit` and `PaginationToken` parameters (emphasis mine):

> ### Limit
>
> Maximum number of users to be returned.
>
> Type: Integer
>   Valid Range: Minimum value of 0. **Maximum value of 60.**
>   Required: No

and

> ### PaginationToken
>
> An identifier that was returned from the previous call
>   to this operation, which can be used to return the next set of items
>   in the list.
>
> Type: String
>   Length Constraints: Minimum length of 1.
>   Pattern: `[\S]+`
>   Required: No